# Integer pairs having biwise AND equal to 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, time-complexity

Two integers x and y form a magical pair, if the result of their Bitwise And equals 0. 
Given an array of integers, find for every array element whether it forms a magical pair with some other array element or not.

Input

First line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case has an integer N denoting the number of elements in the given array. 
The second line contains N single space-separated integers  a1,a2,...an denoting the elements of the given array.

Output

For each test case ,print N space separated integers in a line.
If ai forms a magical pair with any other element of the given array , then  ans'i should be equal to 1. Otherwise ans'i is 0.

Constraints

1<=N,Ai<=10^6

I tried brute force. For each element I checked if the bitwise AND of this number is zero or not with any other element present in the array. Obviously, it had a time complexity of O(N^2) and most of my test cases timed out

This problem is here: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/test/netapp-codenet-2017/algorithm/d2d1f6a92c6740278682e88ed42068a4/

Can anyone suggest me a better approach or algorithm so it passes the time limit?

Brute force code:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int a[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
int ans[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (a[i] & a[j] == 0)
            ans[i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << ans[i] << " ";
```

Comment: please, show some code. It helps to better understand whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: @dorKKnight added

Comment: Do you have an idea how much it is too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a binary tree for all the numbers like a Trie.

For example, if you have array 3 6 2 9 10, binary array would look like

arr = 11, 110, 10, 1001, 1010, and the tree would like

```
                                     root
                                /             \
                               0               1
                                 \           /   \ 
                                  1         0     1
                                 / \       / 
                                0   1     0   
                                 \         \   
                                  1         1
```

If we iterate through each element in binary array, the number(answer) matching the condition should have 0 for every set bit in the element and either 0 or 1 for unset bit in the element.

Now, we only need to traverse these bits into the tree. And if we are able to do it, then there exists at least one number satisfying the condition.

Time complexity O(N).
Reason:- There are n numbers. Each number is of 32 bit binary length. New node creation will take O(1). Therefore, O(32N) => O(N). Same  time for inv_arr.

Note: **Try converting the numbers into 32 bit binary numbers as it will cover all the numbers specified in the range. Otherwise it will result in a problem. Here 6 and 9 forms a magical pair, but 0110 in the inv_arr cannot be traversed and will result in no magical pair present as traversal of leftmost 0 cannot be done. If all numbers will be represented with same length binary, tree traversal will give correct answer.**

Code

```java
public class BinaryNode {

    char c;
    public BinaryNode left;
    public BinaryNode right;

    public BinaryNode(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}

public class BinaryTree {

    public BinaryNode root;

    public BinaryTree(char c) {
        root = new BinaryNode(c);
    }

    public void addToTree(String s) {
        BinaryNode node = this.root;
        int length = s.length();
        for (int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            BinaryNode newNode;
            if (s.charAt(i) == '0') {
                 newNode = addCharToTree(node.left, s.charAt(i));
                 node.left = newNode;
            } else {
                newNode = addCharToTree(node.right, s.charAt(i));
                node.right = newNode;
            }
            node = newNode;
        }
    }

    private BinaryNode addCharToTree(BinaryNode node, char c) {
        if (node == null)
            return new BinaryNode(c);
        return node;
    }


}


public class Solution {

  private static void findMagicalPairs(List<Integer> list) {
        // for creating 32 char long binary string list
        List<String> binaryNumberList = list.stream()
                .map(num -> Long.toBinaryString( Integer.toUnsignedLong(num) | 0x100000000L ).substring(1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // dummy character as root
        BinaryTree binaryTree = new BinaryTree('c');
        binaryNumberList.forEach(binaryTree::addToTree);
        List<Boolean> booleanList = binaryNumberList.stream()
                                     .map(s -> hasMagicalPair(s, binaryTree.root))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static boolean hasMagicalPair(String s, BinaryNode node) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
            return true;
        if (node == null)
            return false;
        String substring = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
        if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '1')
            return hasMagicalPair(substring, node.left) ;
        return hasMagicalPair(substring, node.left) || hasMagicalPair(substring, node.right);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, with this algorithm 0x11 and 0x22 will **not** be marked as magical, since xoring these values gives 0xEE and 0xDD, neither of which will be found in O(1)  while looking up neither 0x11 nor 0x22. Note however that 0x11 & 0x22 gives, in fact, zero.

Comment: Seems like I missed those cases.
For every unset bit in the original arr, we'll have to check for both the bits in the tree instead of XOR-ing with 1*

Comment: Answer edited. Time complexity would still be the same but the worse case will have a lot of operations to perform, to account to every branch in the tree. Solution will work best for large **n** but relatively small numbers.

Comment: I don't know C++, but I can write it in Java if you want.

Comment: Sure. Thanks in advance

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your solution, but I don't think this runs in `O(n)`. In `hasMagicalPair`, you recurse on both the left and right child if the last character of your string is a "0". So if your input string here consists of a single "1" followed by 31 "0"s, you will recurse both left and right on every level except the last one, thus traversing the entire trie and spending `O(n)` time for a single call to `hasMagicPair`. By the same argument, `n/2` strings ending with `n/2` zeroes will each run in `O(n)` time, for `O(n^2)` total. It is more efficient than brute force though.

Comment: The `n` mentioned are the number of elements in the array and have no relation with tree height. Since, the question statement says that `A[i] <= 10^6`, we can represent those number in 20 bits, so the height of the tree is fixed. In this solution, height of the tree is 32 +1(root node), but it can be optimized to have only 20+1 height. Since, the height is fixed no matter how many numbers are there in array, lookup is constant, even if whole tree has to be parsed.

Comment: The `n` does not have a relation to the height of the tree, but it does have a relation to the size of the tree. In a worst case scenario, the first and last bit of each number is set, meaning that all root to leaf paths have length 20 (if you are using unsigned integers). Obviously, each path doesn't have 20 unique nodes that do not appear in any other paths,  but the number of nodes in the tree *will* be linearly dependent on the number of numbers in your input array. If you explore the entire tree due to recursing both left and right, you will use `O(n)` time.

Comment: Like I mentioned in an earlier comment, the running time of the lookup does not depend on the length of a path, but on the size of the tree, due to this line in your code: 
`hasMagicalPair(substring, node.left) || hasMagicalPair(substring, node.right);`. A consequence of this is that you might traverse (almost) the entire tree.

Comment: Can you please give an example of 4 bit array where we have to traverse almost whole tree n/2 times.

Comment: @VatsalJain Just have all combinations of 1/2 bits ones and 1/2 bits zeros: 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12. The tree has 19 nodes, and there is exactly one node that forms a magical pair with any one of these values. The search for the magical pair with 3 traverses 16 nodes. With 5: 14 nodes, with 6: 9 nodes. The others are skipped since they were already matched. On average, those that we look up for take 13 nodes > 2/3 N.

Comment: @MichaelVeksl, there are 19 nodes, but I'm getting 6, 7, 8 traversals for 3, 5, 6 respectively. But, still operations are high.. I think, the fixed bit length can be removed to reduce the size of the tree and a caching system can be introduced to find pairs. A fully branched tree in this case might
 have less than n^2 complexity, but it varies with data.

Comment: Seems like worst case will be n^2 though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry for the long answer :)

**Problem:** I think the problem with your brute force is that you are performing each checking twice (in both directions). Moreover, a lot of checkings are unnecessary.
You can easily reduce the number of iterations by doing every checking only once (and only the necessary ones).

**Key idea:** You should not start the inner loop from `0`.

**Note:** The first of the following sections only introduce the second, but the second section is the one that answers your question.

*The whole code provided here is only meant to illustrate the stated ideas, nothing more*.

---

## 1 - Find all possible magical pairs

Here we are trying to find all possible magical pairs in the given vector avoiding to check multiple times the same pair.

A solution could be:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> magical_pairs(const std::vector<int> & data)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size()-1; ++i) // Stop at second to last
    {
        for(size_t j = i+1; j < data.size(); ++j) // Start from i+1 and not 0
        {
            if((data[i] & data[j]) == 0)
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(data[i], data[j]));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, you check all possible pairs **only once**.

According to me, if you want to get all possible magical pairs, **you cannot reduce the complexity less than what it takes to check all possible pairs only once**.
But if someone has a better solution, I will be very interested to hear it (read it).

You can run an example this way:

```
std::vector<int> input_array {3, 12, -6, 27, 8, 18, -66, 47, 11}; // input example

for(const std::pair<int, int> & mp : magical_pairs(input_array))
    std::cout << mp.first << " : " << mp.second << std::endl;
```

The results for this example:

> 3 : 12
>   3 : 8
>   12 : 18
>   8 : 18

---

## 2 - Check whether a number has a magical pair or not

Now that we know how to avoid to check already checked pairs, we will reuse the same principle to realize the function you want.

You want to check for every number in the array whether they have a magical pair in the array or not.
In this case, we don't want to check all possible magical pairs, only one match is sufficient to determine if a number has a pair. Moreover, when we find a match, we can set two results at a time (one for each number of the pair).
You can see that this way, we will be able to significantly reduce the number of iterations.

It leads us to proceed as follows:

- Check every pair only once
- Stop evaluation of a number at first match
- Determine two results per match --> don't perform the search if already set

Knowing this, a solution could be:

```
std::vector<bool> has_magical_pair(const std::vector<int> & data)
{
    std::vector<bool> result(data.size(), false);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size()-1; ++i) // From 0 to second to last
    {
        if(!result[i]) // search for a magical pair only if not already found
        {
            for(size_t j = i+1; j < data.size(); ++j) // From i+1 to last
            {
                if((data[i] & data[j]) == 0)
                {
                    // Set two results at a time
                    result[i] = true;
                    result[j] = true;
                    break; // Exit the inner loop at first match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, you will be **much more efficient than the brute force** method.

You can run an example this way:

```
std::vector<int> input_array {3, 12, -6, 27, 8, 18, -66, 47, 11};

for(bool hmp : has_magical_pair(input_array))
    std::cout << hmp << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The results for this example:

> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,

I think you will be able to adapt the code of this example to your use case quite easily.

---

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the operations you do first.

In the example you have 3 6 2 9 10

When you do it by brute force you first do

> 3 & 6

And after doing all the

> 3 & y

you repeat

> 6 & 3

. If you find how to avoid repeating this, you'll solve the problem.

Comment: No, the time complexity still would be O(N^2)

Comment: Doesn't matter. The order matters which is still square of N

Comment: You can also stop looking when you find the first match. And you can set `ans[j] = 1` immediately, and skip any elements for which `ans` is already set.

Comment: And asymptotic complexity doesn't tell you how long anything takes in the first place, only how that time scales as the number of inputs increases. So even if a change doesn't affect asymptotic complexity, it can still materially improve run time.

Comment: @Useless As the order of N can be upto 10^6 , nothing less than O(N*log N) can pass. I need a better algorithm or some property I can use

Comment: Well, you say it's N^2 but I tried to do a simple solution in C++ and worked. https://pastebin.com/U678yjXX